# How To disable Community extension in Magento ver. 1.9.1.1

Tags: magento

I have developed a extension in magento community folder, but even after disabling form admin panel it is still showing, i have disabled cache too but still not disabled please help me

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <my_module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Shipping />
            </depends>
        </my_module>
    </modules>
</config>`
```

here my config.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <my_module>
            <module>0.0.1</module>
        </my_module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <my_module>
                <class>My_Module_Model</class>
            </my_module>
        </models>
    </global>
    <default>
        <carriers>
            <my_module>
                <active>1</active>
                <model>my_module/carrier</model>
                <title>My Module</title>
                <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                <sallowspecific>0</sallowspecific>
            </my_module>
        </carriers>
    </default>
</config>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To totally disable the extension you need to set it  false to the module file

```
<config>
<modules>
    <my_module>
        <active>false</active>
        <codePool>community</codePool>
        <depends>
            <Mage_Shipping />
        </depends>
    </my_module>
</modules>
```

Disabling a module from System Configuration > Current Configuration Scope > Advanced > Advanced > Disable Module Output
disables only module's output as it says.

Answer (score 0):

To truly disable a module you need to edit the extension of the xml file in etc/modules. Change it from `My_module.xml to My_module.html`. If you set it to false, the module is disabled but if there are classes that extend from the module class they will still do it even if set to false, so it is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

**to disable your community module from control just go to app/etc/modules/find your module_name.xml file and set false**

```
<config>
<modules>
    <my_module>
        <active>false</active>
        <codePool>community</codePool>
        <depends>
            <Mage_Shipping />
        </depends>
    </my_module>
</modules>
```

ok, now go to your community folder etc/config.xml and set 1 to 0

```
<default>
        <carriers>
            <my_module>
                <active>0</active>
                <model>my_module/carrier</model>
                <title>My Module</title>
                <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                <sallowspecific>0</sallowspecific>
            </my_module>
        </carriers>
    </default>
```

it's done. tell me anything to move you out from this problem thanks.